# What is a component class in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We can create a component class by invoking React.createClass(), but what is a "component class"?

Comment: The documentation from reactjs might help. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Comment: `React.createClass` creates a "class" which extends (and so can be treated as) a Component https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html

Comment: [This is a nice document](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/fcb1b6ab493b0c77d589) that covers some terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React's `createClass` is a method which returns a factory function for creating Components with a specific prototype:

```
const Box = React.createClass({
   render() {
       return (<div class="box"></div>);
   }
});
```

While this is a trivial example, it shows that you can later reference this "Component Class" by name either directly or in JSX:

```
let box = React.createElement(Box); // direct

// in some other component's render method:
<Box />
```

either format will return a new instance of that component type.

---

From [the React API docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html):

> One thing that makes components different than standard prototypal classes is that you don't need to call `new` on them. They are convenience wrappers that construct backing instances (via `new`) for you.

Comment: "which returns a factory function" this is wrong, `createClass` return a constructor function.

Comment: Also, it might be worth to note that `<Box />` transpiles to `React.createElement(Box)`.

Comment: @Pavlo you don't call it with `new`, and it returns a new instance every time; I'd call that a factory.

Comment: `React.createElement` used to do it internally, but, surprisingly for me, not anymore: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L33-L36

Comment: You actually don't call it at all, just pass around, so I think it doesn't really matter.